# Aggregate/group into one column by ID to calculate mean & sd over all columns

Tags: r, aggregate

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame), I want to group a data frame by an ID (lets say `Month`) and calculate the mean and standard deviation per group. The difference is that I want the two columns `Rate 1` and `Rate 2` to be combined into one with the mean and sd of both.

```
Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
Aira       1      12        23
Aira       2      18        73
Aira       3      19        45
Ben        1      53        19
Ben        2      22        87
```

The data frame above should be grouped by `Month` and for each month calculate the `mean` rate over both columns. For example, the mean of month 1 should be (12 + 23 + 53 + 19) / 4 = 26.75. I assume the approach for `sd` is similar.

```
Month Mean_rate
1     26.75
2     50
3     32
```

Comment: How those values have come in `mean_rate` column? Could you explain your output?

Comment: It should be the mean of each month using the values from both columns. I updated my question to include an example. I hope that helps

Comment: So just `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(new = mean(Rate1+Rate2)/2)`?

Comment: Is `mean(Rate1+Rate2)/2` always correct? What does it do exactly?

Comment: I'm concerned about the order of addition and division when the mean is calculated.

Comment: No it is not always true. If you had `rate1`, `rate2`, `rate3` then you would divide by 3. So basically you divide with `ncol(df[-c(1:2)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Input data frame
df <- data.frame(Name=sample(letters,5),Month=c(1,2,3,1,2),Rate1=c(12,18,19,53,22),Rate2=c(23,73,45,19,87))

## Split data set on month
df_splitted <- split(df[,3:4],df$Month)

## Desired Output
df_out <- data.frame(Month=as.numeric(names(df_splitted)),
                     Mean=sapply(lapply(df_splitted,unlist),mean),
                     sd=sapply(lapply(df_splitted,unlist),sd),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
## Plot
plot(df_out$Month, df_out$Mean,
ylim=range(c(df_out$Mean-df_out$sd, df_out$Mean+df_out$sd)),
pch=19, xlab="Measurements", ylab="Mean +/- SD",
main="Scatter plot with std.dev error bars")
arrows(df_out$Month, df_out$Mean-df_out$sd, df_out$Month,
        df_out$Mean+df_out$sd, length=0.05, angle=90, code=3)

## Explanation
# Split the data frame into a list of data frame while keeping
# rows with same month value together
temp1 <- split(df[,3:4],df$Month)

# Convert the list of data frames into list of vectors
temp2 <- lapply(temp1,unlist)

# For every vector in list it calculates the mean
sapply(temp2,mean)
```

The resulting object is a vector while names of the vector represent the month for which it is calculated.

Comment: This works but could you explain what it does and what the resulting data type is? I want to use it to draw a scatter plot with errorbars.

Comment: Explanation Added

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to R and I'm having problems working with the resulting data. When I want to plot the means, I had to extract the months for the x-axis (as numbers) and then get just the means for the y axis (using `names()` and `unname()`). Is there an easy way to do this? Or is it possible to store the result in a data frame like the one in my question?

Comment: The `Month` column in the data frame is now a factor, right? Unfortunately, I can't use that to draw arrows such as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032777/scatter-plot-with-error-bars). I tried `as.numeric()` and `levels()` but the levels are in the wrong order and don't match the order of the other columns.