# R: choose the right plot to create a line chart with 3 subgroups, sample size for each point, and significance differences between the subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, line-plot, sample-size

I'm trying to create a line plot like this one (made on Powerpoint):
[image]

**showing the dependency of weight on age (weight~age), for 3 subgroups** (so each group has its own line). I also want the chart to show:

- **sample size for each point, meaning, the number of individuals for each subgroup at each age.**
- **significance differences between the subgroups at each age. (TukeyHSD results)**

one more important thing: I'm gonna have to repeat those graphs for several parameters (like length~age, and width~age), and also might have to do them several times, so **I would really like to avoid manual inserting solutions**, like `geom_text` if possible..

I've tried several options but keep getting "stuck" at some point. for example:

I have tried this code:

```
plot_morphologic <- ggplot(data = weight_table, 
       mapping = aes(x = as.numeric(age), 
                     y = weight, color=POPULATION))+
  geom_line(se=TRUE)
```

but that creates one line for the 3 populations...

I've also tried this:

```
plot_morphologic <- ggline(data=weight_table, x = "age", y = "weight", add = "mean_sd",
       color = "POPULATION")+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = POPULATION), method = "anova", label = "p.signif", 
                     label.y = c(40),na.rm=F)+
  stat_n_text(group="POPULATION")
```

but couldn't split the sample size to each subgroup and couldn't add the significance of the differences between the subgroups.

an example of my data:

```
weight_table1
# A tibble: 246 × 4
   ID         POPULATION age weight
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Shere Khan A      0           13.4 
 2 Shere Khan A      1           14.2 
 3 Shere Khan A      2           17.4 
 4 Serafina   B      0            5.19
 5 Serafina   B      1           15.3 
 6 Serafina   B      2           NA   
 7 Kaa        A      0            7.68
 8 Kaa        A      1            6.92
 9 Kaa        A      2           19.4 
10 Shenzi     C      0            6.96
```

tnx!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve all this with the following base R functions:

1. Plot the axis and the first line with `plot` with parameters `xlim` and `ylim` set to the maximum range you want to plot (usually automatically computed with `1.1*range(yourdata$yourrow)` or so).
2. Plot the two other lines with `lines`.
3. Plot the points and the error bars with `points` and `arrows`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22037078/11304107). Note the amusing rant about the "particularly intuitive parameter `code=3`" ;-)
4. Add the text with `text`.

I do not see why the last step is a problem for repeated use cases, because you can programatically create the label text with `sprintf("n=%i", nrow(yourdata))`.

Comment: thank u!
can u please explain how to "programatically create the label text with sprintf("n=%i", nrow(yourdata))"? do I count manually the sample sizes and the significance levels? how do I add them? all at once or one by one? 
I find it a little wired that there is no function for that in a program made for statistics... haha

Comment: There are functions for these common tasks, of course. To count the number of levels of a factor, you can call `length(levels(x))` where *x* is the categorial variable. for the sample sizes in a data frame, there is `nrow(df)` and `ncol(df)`. You can look up more info by prefixing a question mark, e.g. `?levels` etc. The point of a ststistical programming language is that you do not hace to live with stuff provided out-of-the-box, but that you can write your own fully automated analysis and visialuzation programs.

Comment: And one further hint: To find out how to extract the result of `TukeyHSD`, enter `?TukeyHSD` and read the "Value" section, which desribes the return value. Apparently, you are interested in "p adj" of the return value.